# Bottom border need to be applied for few posts but it's applied for all the post in the page

Tags: css, wordpress

Custom CSS in WordPress while I'm trying to apply bottom border for posts in home page, border is applied to all posts in the page, I need a border for only few posts.

Code I used:

```css
.post { border-bottom: 2px solid #dbdbdb  !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new class and add it to the post that you want to have with border-bottom.

```
.border {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #dbdbdb !important; 
}
```

-- UPDATE --

I just copy-pasted his code, use this:

```
.border {
     border-bottom: 2px solid #dbdbdb; 
}
```

Comment: Try not to use important , its a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `border-bottom` for only few post. You have multiple post and give the posts with which you want the `border-bottom` another class.

Say all your all post has `.post` you could add another class to those you want `border-bottom`.